# XCode No matching codesigning identity found

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, code-signing

I am very new to iOS/iPhone development and I am trying to build an application from it's source, using XCode 5.1 on iOS 7.1.

I am getting below error when I try to build the source:

```
Code Sign error: No matching codesigning identity found: No codesigning identity (i.e.  certificate and private key pair) matching "iPhone Developer" were found. 

CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type "Application" in SKD "iOS 7.1"
```

Is it that I need some kind of certificates to build this source?
I want to build this application and run on a iPhone device.

I have seen number of questions related to code sign, but non have addressed this issue so i am posting it.

Comment: You have to go and read this code signing process into some doc or tutorial!

Comment: do you have a iOS developer account?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it that I need some kind of certificates to build this source?
>   I want to build this application and run on a iPhone device.

You need to be a registered iOS Developer enrolled in the Apple iOS Developer program ($100/year). Then you will need to configure provisioning profiles to allow your iOS device to load the app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really complicated problem and can have many causes (or, speaking from experience, no discernible cause). On thing that can cause this is if you have more than one Mac that you use, or if you have reinstalled an OS, then unless you took special care to export/import your private/public key pair you have multiple private keys. The private key is the foundation for everything - it is used to request your developer certificate. If the developer certificate was requested with a private key other than one you currently have then nothing is going to work.

(and yeah, without a developer account you won't get far)

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about how to put certificates and private keys in keychain access. You have to also understand code signing stuff.
You can refere this link https://www.bignerdranch.com/we-teach/how-to-prepare/ios-device-provisioning/ for more information about the process. This link also has many sub links

Here you'll find exact solution of your problem in "Provisioning, the Hard Way" paragraph

Answer (score 0):

If you run on device, you ned certificates and provisining profiles for the certificate. You need to create developer certificate, add your device id and create provisining file in your developer portal.

The following link may helpful to you and also see developer documentation of apple.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone-sdk-install-apps-on-iphone-devices-for-development--mobile-1441

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH1-SW1